# XLconnect Export a sheet with data and pictures in another file

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to export a sheet with data and pictures from an `.xls` file to another `.xls` (R:XLconnect) but I don't manage to do that for the whole sheet.
Only characters and numbers could be moved but not simply the whole sheet.

It's for moving sheets to another file without any modifications, to integrate that in a loop.

Thank you for your help if you have any idea!

```
library(XLConnect)
XLSopen<-"Test.xls" #contain a sheet call "Caracteristiques" with dataframe, picture of graphics and colors on cells
wb <- loadWorkbook(XLSopen, create = FALSE) # I would like to copy the wole sheet without modifications to an over xls file names "Test1.xls"
```

Comment: Add the code you are writing and a reproducible example based on your data.

Comment: In the question, not in the comment.